# How to restrict Otp input field maxlength to one in Vuejs manually without using libraries?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
      <div class="otp-wrapper">
        <div class="enterprise-details">
          Enter OTP sent in SMS on your mobile XXXX XX 5136.
        </div>
        <div class="verify-wrapper">
          <input class="otp-number" type="text" placeholder="-" />
          <input class="otp-number" type="text" placeholder="-" />
          <input class="otp-number" type="text" placeholder="-" />
          <input class="otp-number" type="text" placeholder="-" />
        </div>
        <div class="receive-otp">
          Did not receive OTP? &nbsp;
          <b style="color: #ee1d24"> Resend Now </b>
        </div>
      </div>
```

How to restrict Otp input  field  maxlength to one in Vuejs? In the first input field, if i try to enter number, automatically it schould move to next field.

Comment: instead manual cod try to checkout this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bachdgvn/vue-otp-input

Comment: I have gone through it, But any idea on how to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a vueJs package for otp input as you want.
https://github.com/bachdgvn/vue-otp-input
If you look at the code of the author, you can write an @change event that will change the focus to the next input field.